# Skip List Implementation C++ - XCode Error

Tags: c++, xcode, list, skip

I am just starting my implementation of my Skip List, and I have tried everything to get rid of this error. My Build Succeeds, but when I put "SList p" into my main program, it fails and said linked reference ld error. What is the problem?

Here is my .h file

```
#ifndef SLIST_H
#define SLIST_H

#include <string>
#include <fstream>

class SList {
public:
    SList();

    // overloaded assignment operator
    SList& operator = (const SList&);

    // copy constructor
    SList(const SList&);

    // destructor
    ~SList();

private:
    const static int DUMMY_VALUE = -1000;
    struct Node {
        int data;
        Node *next;
    };
    struct upperNode {
        upperNode *next;
        Node *down;
    };
    Node *head;
    upperNode *upperHead;
    int length;
};
#endif  // SLIST_H
```

__

My .cpp file

```
#include "SList.h"

SList::SList() {
    length = 0;
    head->data = DUMMY_VALUE;
    head->next = nullptr;
    upperHead->down = head;
    upperHead->next = nullptr;
}
```

and my main

```
#include "SList.h"
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    SList p;
    return 0;
}
```

What am I missing here? I feel like it is terribly obvious I just need a second set of eyes. Thank you.

Comment: XCode usually doesn't require you to input a Makefile

Comment: There are several methods, such as destructor, you just declared but never implemented them.

Comment: BTW, you should include the exact linker error message instead of saying something like 'linked reference ld error'.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared a copy assignment operator, a copy constructor and a destructor, but you don't provide implementations.